# Three.js TextGeometry not showing in scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I followed the examples page but I cannot get TextGeometry to draw. The program runs without exceptions.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
  var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello three.js!!!!', {
    font: font,
    size: 80,
    height: 50,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 10,
    bevelSize: 8,
    bevelSegments: 5
  });
  textmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textmaterial);
  scene.add(textMesh1);
});
camera.position.z = 5;
var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```

Can you please point out where the mistake might be?

Comment: Likely rendering black on black background. `MeshLambertMaterial` requires scene lights. Change it to `MeshNormalMaterial`, for example.

Comment: Mr. Doob has suggested using HTML over the canvas to draw text sprites.  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1321